# Calculate Time Duration that fall within 2 dates

Tags: swift, date, time, duration, dateformatter

How can time (duration) be calculated that fall between 2 date sets? (Hours and minutes - All times in UTC)

```
// 2 date sets (2 daylight periods)
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

let dayStart1 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020-10-06 07:02:42")!
let dayEnd1 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020-10-06 19:20:46")!

let dayStart2 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020-10-07 06:59:40")!
let dayEnd2 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020-10-07 18:58:12")!
```

//MARK: Example 1

Work out Time Duration from below start and end dates that fall within above date sets.

```
let start1 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020-10-06 17:10:00")!
let end1 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020-10-07 03:50:00")!
```

> Should return: 02:10 (2h 10min)

//MARK: Example 2

```
let start2 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020-10-06 17:10:00")!
let end2 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020-10-07 07:59:45")!
```

> Should return: 03:10 (3h 10min)

Comment: Didn't understand your question. And how did you come up with the expected results for  start1/end1 start2/end2 ?  They don't make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called DateInterval. You can simply create date intervals from your dates and get its intersections. Then you can just sum the duration of the results:

```
let fmt = DateFormatter()
fmt.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
fmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
fmt.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!
let dayStart1 = fmt.date(from: "2020-10-06 07:02:42")!
let dayEnd1 = fmt.date(from: "2020-10-06 19:20:46")!
let dayStart2 = fmt.date(from: "2020-10-07 06:59:40")!
let dayEnd2 = fmt.date(from: "2020-10-07 18:58:12")!
let di1 = DateInterval(start: dayStart1, end: dayEnd1)
let di2 = DateInterval(start: dayStart2, end: dayEnd2)
```

---

```
let start1 = fmt.date(from: "2020-10-06 17:10:00")!
let end1 = fmt.date(from: "2020-10-07 03:50:00")!
let workout = DateInterval(start: start1, end: end1)
let intersection1 = di1.intersection(with: workout)
let intersection2 = di2.intersection(with: workout)
let duration = (intersection1?.duration ?? .zero) + (intersection2?.duration ?? .zero)
let dcf = DateComponentsFormatter()
dcf.string(from: duration)  // "2:10:46"
```

---

```
let start2 = fmt.date(from: "2020-10-06 17:10:00")!
let end2 = fmt.date(from: "2020-10-07 07:59:45")!
let workout2 = DateInterval(start: start2, end: end2)
let intersection3 = di1.intersection(with: workout2)
let intersection4 = di2.intersection(with: workout2)
let duration2 = (intersection3?.duration ?? .zero) + (intersection4?.duration ?? .zero)
dcf.string(from: duration2)  // "3:10:51"
```

Answer (score -1):

your results with example1 , example2 are wrong
add these extensions to your project

```
extension TimeInterval{

    func stringFromTimeInterval() -> String {

        let time = NSInteger(self)

        let seconds = time % 60
        let minutes = (time / 60) % 60
        let hours = (time / 3600)

        return String(format: "%0.2d:%0.2d:%0.2d",hours,minutes,seconds)

    }}

extension Date {
 static func getTimeInterval(to: Date, from: Date) -> TimeInterval {
        return to.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - from.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    }

}


  

  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        let start1 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020-10-06 17:10:00")!
        let end1 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020-10-07 07:59:45")!
        print(Date.getTimeInterval(to: end1, from: start1).stringFromTimeInterval())
```